# How to set the name value and choice field value in html form fields without using django-forms?

Tags: html, django

Suppose I want to give user 2 option in html select tag.

i want help to, full MVC implementation in Python.
i dont want to use **django form**.
Sample html code:

```
<form method="POST">
                        <div class="form-row">
                            <div class="name">Name</div>
                            <div class="value">
                                <div class="input-group">
                                    <input class="input--style-5" type="text" name="name" required>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-row">
                                <div class="name">Applying In</div>
                                <div class="value">
                                    <div class="input-group">
                                        <div class="rs-select2 js-select-simple select--no-search">
                                            <select name="subject" required>
                                                <option disabled="disabled" selected="selected"> Applying Department</option>
                                                <option>Backend</option>
                                                <option>Mobile</option>
                                                
                                            </select>
                                            <div class="select-dropdown"></div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `option = request.GET['subject']` in a view.py which will be invoked on form submission. You will get only one option because you are selecting single option in template.

Answer (score 0):

suppose we have a model like this:

```
from django.db import models
from django import forms

class Foo(models.Model):
    CHOICES= (
        ('choice_one', 'choice one'),
        ('choice_two', 'choice two'),
    )
    user_choices= models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=CHOICES)        



class FooForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Foo
        fields = ['user_choices']
```

views:

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect, render
from . import models

def user_choices(request):
    url = request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER')  # get last url
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = models.FooForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            data = models.Foo()
            data.user_choices= request.GET.get('user_choices')
            data.save()
            return redirect(url)
    return render(request, 'user_choices.html', context)
```

then in the template:

```
<form action="{% url 'app_name:user_choices' %}" method="POST"> # url to above function
    <select name ='user_choices'>
        <option name="user_choices" value="choice_one">choice one</option>
        <option name="user_choices" value="choice_two">choice two</option>
    </select>
    <button type="submit">submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: question said not to use Django forms , means manual form

Comment: i'm just using django forms to access form validations. i'm not using django form itself to save data! @Atif